# Scroll to top of an element without using animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

HOw can I scroll to top of an element without using animate()? I googled, but all answers are with animate().

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

I just want to instantly go to the top of an element. In my case, the animate() is not necessary.

Comment: why don't you use just plain HTML (anchors)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('html, body').scrollTop( $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top);
});
```

```css
.dummy {
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Test</button>
<div class="dummy"></div>
<div id="elementtoScrollToID">elementtoScrollToID</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just passing an anchor, pure HTML:

```
<a href="#top">go to top</a>
```

and you just add an `<a name="top"></a>` on the top of your website :)

Comment: I came across this solution. But in my case I'm looking for a javascript/jquery related answer. I've tagged those 2.

Comment: Basic DOM is faster than javascript/jquery... But if you are looking for speed go for Vanilla JS not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You achieve the same affect without jQuery by using [`Window.scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    window.scroll(0,document.getElementById("elementtoScrollToID").offsetTop);
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>

<div id="elementtoScrollToID" style="margin: 800px 0;">
  Scroll to here...
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```